# Имя 'own' не определено

Tags: python, python-3.x

Xотел сделать погоду на пайтоне.
Посмотрел гайд начал делать и вылазит вот так ошибка.

> ```
> line 5, in <module>
>     Owm = Owm('c559c6bfa7d25bdc1e72ccccdb3019a1')
> NameError: name 'Owm' is not defined
> ```

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import pyowm

init()
Owm = Owm('c559c6bfa7d25bdc1e72ccccdb3019a1') 


place = input("В каком городе/стране: ")

observation = Owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("В городе" + place + "сейчас" + w.get_detailed_status())
print ("Температура сейчас в районе" + str(temp))

if temp < 10:
    print ("сейчас холодновато, одень кофту/легкую куртку")
elif temp < 20:
    print("Сейчас тепло, одень легкую кофточку :3")
else:
    print("Сейчас капец как жарко, выпрыгивай в окно и кричи 'Ну че народ, погнали!'")
```

Comment: Такое бывает, когда смотришь в книгу видишь фигу.

Comment: Спать хочу,а доделать тоже хочу) Туплю :3

Comment: Так может стоит сначала основы основ изучить?

Comment: Этот код даже не может выдать указанную в заголовке ошибку, потому что имя ``own`` в нем вообще не встречается.

Comment: исправил,добавил ошибку переделал own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не то и не у того вызываете. Вот пример из документации:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
owm = OWM('c559c6bfa7d25bdc1e72ccccdb3019a1')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
weather = mgr.weather_at_place('Tokyo,JP').weather
temp_dict_kelvin = weather.temperature()   # a dict in Kelvin units (default when no temperature units provided)
temp_dict_kelvin['temp_min']
temp_dict_kelvin['temp_max']
temp_dict_fahrenheit = weather.temperature('fahrenheit')  # a dict in Fahrenheit units
temp_dict_celsius = weather.temperature('celsius')  # guess?

print(temp_dict_celsius)
```

И он работает https://repl.it/repls/CookedAzureBrackets

Comment: А в Google Colab, кстати, ругается: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyowm.owm'`, не знаю с чем там несовместимость