# NameError: name 'OWM' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

При выполнении кода

```
import pyowm 

owm = OWM ('34f35a82e5d31939477bf61e91c57508', Language = "ru")
place = input("В каком городе/стране?: ")

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather()

print(w)
```

Получаю сообщение об ошибке:
`NameError: name 'OWM' is not defined`

Как это исправить?

Comment: `from pyowm import OWM`
правда дальше вы опять обращаетесь к `mgr` и `observation` до этого их нигде не создали/импортировали.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Имя 'own' не определено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154422/%d0%98%d0%bc%d1%8f-own-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyowm import OWM
```

Читайте [документацию](https://pypi.org/project/pyowm/) по `pyowm`

Для лучшего понимания что происходит - гуглите ошибку.

Comment: Да тут не документацию по pyowm читать надо, а основы работы с модулями.

Comment: О привет) где-то я тебя уже видел)

Comment: I have already googled and did not find anything that would help (I do not google programming, but only learn)